# EXCEL | How to get column and row numbers of a cell from only a specific grid dynamically without VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel based tool which extracts numbers from other sheets based on the column and row of the selected cell (the one last clicked on from a specific grid) on the main sheet. The column and row numbers get pasted in cells which don't have a background formula. How is this done?

P.S. This does not use VBA (no macros and it is a .xls file)

Comment: Wait - does the file *do that already*, and you want to know how the sheet does it? If so, it sounds like you're using an add-in and want to know how the add-in works? ...Or are you asking how to do that?

Comment: Could it be using XL4 macros, and a hidden macro sheet?

Comment: @BruceWayne yes I want to know how the sheet does it. And no, not using any add-in. Or macros. I have checked that.

Imagine a 4x4 cell grid. As of now any cell may be selected outside the grid, but the cell LAST SELECTED IN THE GRID is highlighted along with its entire column and row. And its column number and row number are being pasted in two different cells. And, these two cells don't have any formula in them. :/

Comment: We are at an impasse,  we cannot possibly tell you how it is done without seeing the file, and many of us, me included, will not download a file from the internet.  We can only guess.  As far as we know without some code or formula what you are describing is not possible.  So without the file we can't possibly tel you how it is being done.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a macro? .xls does not have a different file extension for a macro enabled file.